# Android Start new activity first time

Tags: android, android-intent, ocr

Android app issue:
I have  MainActivity that when you press a button it opens the camera (an OCR) via Intent and startActivity. The problem is when I press the button in my mobile the first time after the installation, it gets blocked. 
Then, after the first time, it works perfect...

By the way, when I try to execute the app in the android emulator it gives me only one error: "error opening trace file: No such file or directory" I don't know if this error is related with my problem in the mobile.
Here is the intent of MainActivity

```
    Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CaptureActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data.hasExtra("ocrResult")) {
            EditText.setText(data.getExtras().getString("ocrResult"));

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

And here you have the code of the OCR that sends the result to MainActivity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}

public void finish() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("ocrResult", ocrResultView.getText());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    super.finish();
}
```

Finally, the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr"
          android:installLocation="auto" 
          android:versionName="0.5.13" 
          android:versionCode="32"
          >
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

  <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>

  <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:label="@string/app_name">

     <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"              
              >

    </activity> 

    <activity android:name="edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.PreferencesActivity"> </activity>

  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: how do you open your camera? can you post your code

Comment: are you reading some file in your code?

Comment: where are you testing the app on emulator or device?

Comment: First of all thank you for the questions. I am testing the app in both. When I test it in the emulator I receive the error and when I test it on the device it gets blocked only the first time I press the button to open the ocr

Comment: don't hide exceptions, log the exception in catch in onClick without that you don't even know what is happening

Comment: Maybe it is a camera(OCR) matter when I try to open it the first time, than an intent matter...